# What classes are imported in the beginning of a php program?

Tags: php, arrays, class, object, import

Are there any objects/classes which are created/imported automatically to a php program (and therefore are recognized in the program)  ?

I wonder if it is possible to use them in the program.
Take for example the following code:

```
<?php
$places = array("first", "second", "third");
echo "I like the " . $places[0] . ", " . $places[1]. " and " . $places[2] . ".";
?>
```

Are there any classes which are imported in the background to the program?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There are no require, includes, or uses that are being included. This is standard PHP code for an array and output.

Comment: On the other hand, when I added the get_declared_classes() function to the above code, It talled me that the class array is imported for some reason

Comment: I suppose that this could be true for any language. Each language has its own set of internals that it must include to be functional. Just because the class is declared doesn't mean it's being used. I would take a look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.classes.php for a better understanding. Extensions for instance will include classes/functions that could be used, but the code you put above doesn't use any of them.

Comment: This is true, but if they are imported, then it is possible to use them without any explicit import.

Comment: It is possible to use without explicit import. That's one of the things that's nice (and dreadful) about PHP. You can use whatever extensions are compiled without explicitly including them.

Comment: And each extension has its own classes (one extension for example is zend). Ok, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

PHP includes it's own standard library per release. One class that comes to mind is DateTime().

Comment: So all the classes in the php src code are recognized automatically without import?

Comment: yes, it's part of the base library. Just like how in python auto imports list and dictionary datasets, php auto imports arrays and the like.